# Oscar Dashboard requests /static/css/base.css instead of /static/oscar/css

Tags: python, css, django, django-oscar

I'm somewhat new to Django, but I have previously installed Django Oscar on it's own to test it out and it was working perfectly fine.

However I'm now building a project which uses Django-Allauth with a Custom User Model, and I have installed Django-Oscar, however when I launch the Dashboard it doesn't load in it's entirety, ([Screenshot of Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrXlQ.png)) I see from the Run log that it currently requests my static/css/base.css, however when I launched it before I see it goes to /static/oscar/css to get it's stylesheets. I believe that this may be the problem (please let me know if you think otherwise).

I've gone through my settings time and time again to see if there is an issue somewhere but I can't seem to pinpoint anything, so I wanted to post here in help of a resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Below is my settings.py posted:

```
from oscar.defaults import *
from oscar import OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
from oscar import get_core_apps


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'Users',
    'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    # ... include the providers you want to enable:

    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
] + get_core_apps()

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Clip.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
                 ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Clip.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

    # Oscar-Django Authentication
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

)


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Users.User'

SITE_ID = 1


# AllAuth Settings

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'Users.forms.SignupForm'


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'


CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap3"
```